# IIS7 stop serving file on request but allows ajax callback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, iis-7, privacy

Basically I'm a bit lost I need to allow a jQuery callback the ability to access a web function via an ajax post.

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/Methods/Credit.asmx/PaymentHoldingDocument1",
         data: "{iCredits: " + $('#creditAmount').val() + ", iClientId: " + window.iUserId + "}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json"
        });
```

This then updates a document in a directory \Payment\Holding\1.txt but I don't want people the ability to view the document once it's been created so I want to hide that once it's been created. Using the following in the web.config I've been able to stop people viewing the file but it also stops the web method from writing to it as well.

```
<security>
   <requestFiltering>
      <hiddenSegments>
         <add segment="\Payment\" />
      </hiddenSegments>
   </requestFiltering>
 </security>
```

Is there something I'm missing? or is it something I can not do?.

Also removing `IUSR` or `IIS_USR` isn't an option as this stops me writing to the file as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Building JSON manually is a **BAD** idea. Use `JSON.stringify({iCredits: ..., iClientId: ...})` instead!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify looking there it says in the description that it doesn't send them in any particular order... but my web method will be expecting them in that order I think, or is that me being anal?

Comment: I do want to learn more stuff like this though cause I'm finding myself using webmethods a lot at the moment. Would be good to be up to speed with it all. Do you have any decent tut urls you could ping my way :)

Comment: If you need a particular order you need to use an array. However, if your server-side code expects a JSON object it will not expect it to have a particular order.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a denial on *.txt files by creating a request filter in IIS?  That prevents things like the web.config files from being downloaded.

Comment: Will that just stop browser displaying the file or stop IUSR's from read/writing to it?

Comment: @SimonLongson browser.  Anything that happens on the server, i.e. on a code-behind page, will be subject to normal access rights not dictated by IIS.